# Count occurrences of feature pairs for a given set of mappings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to aggregate a DataFrame such that for each `from`, and each `to` given in the `mappings` table (e.g. `.iloc[0]` where `a` maps to `b`), we take the corresponding `f#` (feature) columns from the `labels` table, and find the number of times that that feature mapping occurred.

The expected output is given in the `output` table.

**Example**: in the `output` table we can see there are 4 times when a `from` element mapped to a `to` element (i.e. where the `from` had an `f1` feature and the `to` had an `f2` feature). We can deduce these as being `a->b`, `a->c`, `d->e`, and `d->g`.

**Mappings**

```
    from    to
0   a       b
1   a       c
2   d       e
3   d       f
4   d       g
```

**Labels**

```
    name    f1  f2  f3
0   a       1   0   0
1   b       0   1   0
2   c       0   1   0
3   d       1   1   0
4   e       0   1   0
5   f       0   0   1
6   g       1   1   0
```

**Output**

```
    f1  f2  f3
f1  1   4   1
f2  1   2   1
f3  0   0   0
```

**Table construction code**

```
# dataframe 1 - the mappings
mappings = pd.DataFrame({
    'from': ['a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
    'to': ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
})

# dataframe 2 - the labels
labels = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    'f1': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    'f2': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    'f3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
})

# dataframe 3 - the expected output
output = pd.DataFrame(
    index = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3'],
    data = {
        'f1': [1, 1, 0],
        'f2': [4, 2, 0],
        'f3': [1, 1, 0],
})
```

Comment: How do the rows `d` and `g` work in the labels? Since they have two values with `1`?

Comment: That would mean that `d` has the feature `f1`, and `g` also has the feature `f1`, so we would +=1 the case where `f1` -> `f1`. This happens to be the only case where that happens, as seen in the output table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we `melt` your `labels` dataframe from columns to rows, so we can easily match on them. Then we merge these values to our `mapping` and finally use `crosstab` to get your final result:

```py
labels = labels.set_index('name').where(lambda x: x > 0).melt(ignore_index=False).dropna()

df = (
    mappings.merge(labels.add_suffix('_from'), left_on='from', right_on='name')
    .merge(labels.add_suffix('_to'), left_on='to', right_on='name')
)

final = pd.crosstab(index=df['variable_from'], columns=df['variable_to'])
final = (
    final.reindex(index=final.columns, fill_value=0)
    .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
).convert_dtypes()
```

**Output**

```
    f1  f2  f3
f1   1   4   1
f2   1   2   1
f3   0   0   0
```

---

Note:

- [`melt(ignore_index=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) requires `pandas >= 1.1.0`
- [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) requires `pandas >= 1.0.0`

---

For `pandas < 1.1.0` we can use `stack` instead of `melt`:

```
(
    labels.set_index('name')
    .where(lambda x: x > 0)
    .stack()
    .reset_index(level=1)
    .rename(columns={'level_1': 'variable', 0: 'value'})
)
```

Comment: And for lowier pandas version should be used stack ;)